# I can't connect my Website to Database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have recently deployed my new website, I use GoDaddy Unlimited Hosting and I'am unable to connect to the database for some reason.

Here's my code for connecting my website to the database:

```
<?php

ob_start();
session_start();

// db properties
define('DBHOST','some.example.ip.Address');
define('DBUSER','username');
define('DBPASS','password');
define('DBNAME','database-name');

$conn = @mysql_connect (DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS);
$conn = @mysql_select_db (DBNAME);

if(!$conn) {

    die('Some Error Message');

}

define('included', 1);

?>
```

And Instead of connecting my website to the database and showing the content It shows the die() error message I have used above, And I tried adding `if (! $conn) { mysql_error() or die('some message'); }` I can see my website but can't see the db content and when I submit any form It shows this message `Query failed. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you using valid data? And in future use `mysqli_*`, `mysql_*` is deprecated

Comment: What version of PHP is the server running? Because if it's later than 5.5 you'll have problems using `mysql_` functions. Replace them with `mysqli_`.

Comment: No I'm use `mysql_` throughout my website

Comment: Are you sure you entered the correct password? The error message looks like something is wrong with the password.

Comment: I'm using the latest PHP version

Comment: I think your username `root` and mysql server `localhost` is bad..

Comment: I'll try `mysqli_` as I also heard Its pretty secure

Comment: check username and password as stated above comment

Comment: I still can't connect to my website using `mysqli` and my IP, username, password are correct

Comment: question: are you using the PHP snippet in your server (the same server where your database resides) or are you using it locally trying to connect remotely to the server?

Comment: I'm using an actual web server from GoDaddy

Comment: when you created the User, did you give that user **full privileges** to the database you created?

Comment: I just created the databse

Comment: umm.. you need to create a user, and then make sure you give them full privileges to that database. You can do this through Cpanel

Comment: I'm doing It right now

Comment: Yup I just did, now I should use that user and password to connect?

Comment: yes of course. Try that.

Comment: Nope, I can't see any difference I also tried `mysqli_` and also `mysql_` shows the same thing

Comment: Also I changed the ip address, username, password and db name just for privacy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86623/discussion-between-codegodie-and-arqetech).

Answer (score 1):

Look into using PDO.  `mysql_connect` is deprecated and generally not considered secure.  However, it should still work.
Here's a simple PDO connection:

```
TRY {   
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=NameofDB','username','password');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);      
}
CATCH(PDOEXCEPTION $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
    die ('sorry for your luck!');
}
```

There are lots of tutorials around the web for PDO implementation, and it's generally considered he way to go.

Comment: Thank You, But I already got my answer, I just had to change my IP address to `localhost` :)